# Converting 3 axis vectors to a rotation matrix

Tags: rotation, matrix, vector

I am trying to get a rotation matrix (in 3dsmax) from 3 vectors that form an axis (all 3 vectors are aligned by 90 degrees each other)

Somewhere I read that I could build a rotation matrix just by inserting in every row one vector at a time (source: http://renderdan.blogspot.cz/2006/05/rotation-matrix-from-axis-vectors.html)

So, I built a matrix with these example vectors

x-axis : [-0.194624,-0.23715,-0.951778]

y-axis : [-0.773012,0.634392,0]

z-axis : [-0.6038,-0.735735,0.306788]

But for some reason, if I try to convert this matrix to eulerangles, I receive this rotation: (eulerAngles 47.7284 6.12831 36.8263) ... which is totally wrong, and doesn't align to my 3 vectors at all.

I know that rotation is quite difficult to understand, may someone shed some light? :)

Comment: Are your axis vectors all of unit length? Have you possibly mixed row-major and column-major representations?

Comment: your both representations are only valid relative to the same space. are you sure you are not mixing spaces (using euler angles in other spaces) ?

Comment: Thank you for your fast replies.
Yes, the 3 vectors are all of unit length.
I also tried both row-major and column-major representations.
Furthermore, the vectors are calculated in world space.

This is basically the code:

rot_matrix = matrix3 x_vector[1] y_vector[2] z_vector[3] [0,0,0]
custom_angle = rot_matrix as eulerangles

... which, following the above example, returns these values:
matrix3 [-0.194624,-0.773012,-0.6038] [-0.23715,0.634392,-0.735735] [-0.951778,0,0.306788] [0,0,0]
eulerAngles -39.3953 -30.0667 -23.1288

... Which is weird, as If I draw the vector, they are orthogonal.

Comment: Sorry, it actually looks like the problem was the "matrix as eulerAngles" maxscript command, not a fault in the math used :S
I simply assigned the transform matrix directly to my item, and everything works fine now :S

Answer (score 1):

A rotation matrix can be built by using the axis of the coordinate system you're rotating into. As others stated in the comments you have to make sure you don´t mix row- and column-major matrices and dont mix any coordinate spaces. Since the math you used is correct, as you said, the problem must be somewhere else in your code.